# Security Objectives

Tags: 12.04, security, desktop-environments

- New to Linux
- New to Ubuntu
- Objective: Better understanding security
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Hello,

I am going through the security guide on Ubuntu documentation, and I am getting demotivated fast. I think the reason is because I have no understanding of what type of threats are possible towards me. So blindly following tutorials without any objective of my own is getting boring.

To give you an idea of my understanding; how does the existence of ports cause threats? and even if this question is answered I wouldn't know what else to look out for.

What I would like your help in is suggested reading, to start someone on taking control of their own security. To understand the scope of the battle field and identify what will effect me.

The documentation should be technical in nature to properly understand cause and effect.

If you can also categorize using the following genres:

- Global information on threats
- Beginners information on Threats/Security
- Interim
- Advance

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Beginners information on Threats/Security**

Some might consider this question too broad, but narrowing it down to just the desktop because of your desktop-environments tag, start with these three rules:

1. Use a strong password that is impossible for anyone to guess, and if you write your password down, don't leave your password anywhere where people might be able to find it.
2. Don't install crapware. Use the Ubuntu Software Center as your software source.
3. If you have issues about security when other people have physical access to your computer, encrypt the disk that Ubuntu is installed on and use a strong password to access the encrypted volume.

Comment: Thank you @karel, this does seem to be the general security information floating around and I am familiar with this but I think what I am looking for is more technical information to understand cause and effect. I think this is something I should have specified in my question. I will update

Comment: Would you be able to also suggest how I can reduce the scope of this?

Comment: That's a hard question to answer properly because a house is not secure if you lock all the doors and then leave a window open, so it's nice to have all the topics together in a single question. However maybe it would be possible to break the question down into separate categories as you did at the end of the question, and then each category could be the topic of a separate question.

Comment: Ok I think the initial problem is for me to understand what all of those doors and windows are and how many of them there are, so I think the best approach is for me to delete this question and somehow ask a question that will identify those elements. Once that's done I will do as you suggest.

Comment: Before I do that, do you have any suggestions that will help identify those aspects?

Comment: Before I reply I need to know if your question includes server security which is in some ways very different from desktop security. Server security is a very broad topic, and it is a matter for questions that go into minute details which you can find at [Server Fault Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions).

Comment: I will say desktop security

Comment: Here are some security topics: physical, local, files and file system, password & encryption, kernel, networking, security preparation, & what to do during and after a break-in. Or else you can reduce the clutter by using the original 4 categories at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide the reading material you need exactly, but let me tell you what do most Ubuntu users agree universally:

**It's safe.** The Communications-Electronics Security Group of the United Kingdom Government tested many OSes, and Ubuntu was given the highest score among these. There are very few viruses for Linux, and the latest Ubuntu releases already have these patched, hence you'll never find an anti-virus made for Linux issues-most that are available for Linux are meant to prevent Windows viruses from being transmitted.

**It's stable.** Very stable. The chances of an Ubuntu PC crashing frequently is way less than a Windows PC.

**Top IT-and other-cos rely on Ubuntu.** Google, Facebook, Yahoo, Heroku, Amazon.... so many of your favourite and necessary websites are powered by Ubuntu server. Sony uses an Ubuntu PC to compile the firmware for every Xperia smartphone. Studios like Pixar and Weta Digital, and movies like James Cameron's Avatar used server farms running Ubuntu to generate their movies.

**Highest on reliability.** Governments and high-risk organizations use Linux and Ubuntu to store and process data since getting through it's safety is not an easy task.

**Ports do not increase your risk.** All versions of Ubuntu ports-Edubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu etc. are based on a version of Ubuntu. If there are issues, then it's universal across each Ubuntu port and the primary base OS, not just a particular port.

Stop worrying. You're better with Ubuntu than Windows.